# How to offset the beginning_of_day method in Rails by 4 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created an event listing app where events disappear once they've expired. For instance, a user might see a concert is happening Jan 28 from 9pm - 11pm. From 12 am on Jan 28 to 10:59 pm that event will show up. At 11pm the event is gone.

A nightclub would have a similar event from Jan 28 at 10 pm to Jan 29 at 2 am. Currently, at 12 am Jan 29 that nightclub's event disappears even though it's still active.

I have a scope that checks if an event is on a particular day, but it's not returning early morning events.

```
scope :on, lambda {|date|
  raw_sql = '("event_occurrences"."start_time" BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR ("event_occurrences"."end_time" BETWEEN ? AND ?)'
  scope = includes(:occurrences)
  scope.where(raw_sql, date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day + 4.hours, date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day + 4.hours)
}
```

I think overriding the beginning_of_day and end_of_day methods so that the day starts at 4 am rather than 12 am would be a better way to go since that accurately reflects nightlife (with some leeway).

It'll make the user experience better since users see events for "today" and "tomorrow". If I had the offsetting working correctly (code above), at 1am on Jan 29 "today" would display the nightclub, but it would also show concerts that begin at 9pm on Jan 29. Those concerts should show as "tomorrow".

How would I build a utility class that overrides those methods?

Answer (score 1):

You basically want all the events which start on a given date and end after the given datetime.

I would use a chain of scopes like this, which will receive a datetime and return those records which match this criteria:

```
scope :active_on, ->(dt) { where("(start_time BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (end_time BETWEEN ? AND ?)", dt.beginning_of_day, dt.end_of_day, dt.beginning_of_day, dt.end_of_day) }
scope :active_for_datetime, ->(dt) { active_on(dt).where("end_time > ?", dt) }
```

You can then call the scope `.active_for_datetime(whenever)` and pass in a datetime for now, or any other particular moment.

Changing `beginning_of_day` to be 4am is just mental. Don't do that.

Comment: But this doesn't offset the time 4 hours? Adding `+4.hours` to the `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` chains aren't responding right either.